# Experience Analytics Entry/Exit pages display [unknown page]

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

Can anyone shed some light on why I am seeing numerous entries for [unknown page] in the Experience Analytics -> Behavior -> Pages -> Entry pages/Exit Pages reports?

[image]

I need to track down what is causing so many [unknown page] entries in the reports and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: From your comment below, it looks like static and media files are tracked. xDB does not track static files or media by default. Could you include more information about the files being tracked? Are they in the media library or are they static? Is there anything special about your Sitecore configuration that could have caused this?

Comment: Some of the files I'm seeing in the Page Entry URLs are assets hosted outside of sitecore. Files like .js, .css, some logo image .gifs are being displayed in the URL report and they aren't hosted in Sitecore, but referenced on the pages. I think this explains a majority of the [unknown pages] because these items don't actually exist in Sitecore.

Comment: Bill, could you take a look at `<param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">` in the ***Sitecore.config***? Both in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline and in the `preprocessRequest` pipeline? What extensions are listed there?

Comment: preprocessRequest contains: aspx, ashx, asmx, asp, jpeg, jpg  httpRequestBegin contains: aspx

Comment: do you have any updates on this? have you been able to solve the issue?

Comment: at this point I don't have a conclusive resolution. I am working with Sitecore support to see what possible resolutions we can come up with though. I'll update with more information as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: @BillCacy Hi there, were you able to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @Örvar, it ended up being caused by assets (css/js files) from another one of the client's sites that referenced links provided by the Sitecore instance. So the entry point wasn't tracked and therefore listed as unknown.The resolution was a combination of the 2 answers listed here. #2 in Sitecore Climber's answer helped track it down and then we added some logic to exclude some urls from tracking similar to what Dmytro Schevchenko pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

The **[Unknown page]** entries may appear due to following reasons:

1. Items may have been deleted which were already tracked.
2. Pages are opened and tracked which are not Sitecore items e.g. You created a test.aspx page in root folder and open it, This page does not have a corresponding item in Sitecore and will show as Unknown.

You can check URLs and Names of these pages in "Page URLs" section in Behavior tab.

Comment: Yeap. In our site we have lot of those because an intermediary page that gets hit after the user logs-in in through a different service.

Comment: Makes sense. When I look at the Page URLs, I'm seeing various entries for .gif and .css files. Is there a way to exclude assets from those reports?

Answer (score 3):

Tracked pages have an `ItemId` field that is saved to the Collection database. During the generation of reports, all information about the page will be fetched from the corresponding Sitecore item. In case there is no associated item in the content tree, `[unknown page]` will be shown.

This will become a problem when you are tracking page hits that don't have a Sitecore item associated with them. If you have such a page tracked, there are two options for improving the reports:

### Don't track the page

I've described the various ways to prevent a page from being tracked. See this post:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1456/104

### Override item information

You can track custom pages and override the item and URL information for the page hit. You can do that by including the following in the code of your page:

```
Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.SetItemProperties(itemId, "en", itemVersion);
Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.SetUrl("/some/url");
```