# Why am I seeing a view model type name in Path Analyzer funnel

Tags: path-analyzer

My client is on a Sitecore 8.1.2 site in MVC and while reviewing the Path Analyzer I noticed a View Model type name was showing up in one of my funnels. Does anyone know why this might happen, whether this is an indication of an issue and if there is any way to prevent this from happening?

**UPDATE:** I was looking through the code-base and found that there is an `HttpPost` action named `BuildSearchResultsViewModel` that I expect could be the culprit. This action (which should probably be renamed) is called via on search button click. While I know that action routes really are paths, this doesn't really have any meaning to the client. Is there a way to selectively hide these entries from the path analyzer or to create a more meaningful label for them (e.g. "Search Button Click")?

[image]

We do not have any custom reporting/analytics code running on that page that would cause it to show up, as far as I know. If there is any specific configuration or code that would be relevant for this issue that I am not aware of then please let me know and I will update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ignore your custom ajax response you can cancel the request tracking in your controller action code:

`Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Cancel()`

This is to be used when you need to cancel a *single* request tracking.

**Note**: It will work for future paths/requests only.

In order to remove the current irrelevant records, you will probably need to lookup mongodb for tracking history, remove unnecessary records and rebuild your reporting db.

**Update**: check this post for different cancellation techniques as well: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1456/982

Comment: If I do this, will it cancel tracking for subsequent requests that occur after running that search?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel this is for individual requests. check updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much! I will be leaving the question open for a short while so as not to dissuade people from providing alternate solutions ;)