# Ways to block SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE from being deployed?

Tags: experience-analytics, pipelines, cookies

Because of EU legislation, sometimes you have to block tracking cookies from being deployed. In Sitecore's case this would mean the SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE, since it's not absolutely necessary for the functioning of the site (it's necessary for analytics/personlization).

Looking through Sitecore, this cookie is deployed by the `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureDevice` pipeline. But I always dislike overriding Sitecore pipeline if I can avoid it (rather add pipepeline components if necessary).

So, have you found other/better ways to to block the SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE from being deployed?

**Secondary Answer (Edit):** 
The link provided by sestocker in the comment has excellent options, such as settig Tracker.Enable to false in the pre-initialization stage of your page, etc. Those work really well for disabling the SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE, but Sitecore Climbers answer also works, and will help with for example the #lang cookie, since there's no switch to turn that one off.

Comment: Check out this thread: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/disable-xdb-tracking-for-single-requests. I think the best approach would be a pipeline where you set Tracker.Enabled to false.

Comment: @sestocker thanks! I don't know how I didn't find that post earlier. I'll try those out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create your own class:

```
public class ClearCookieHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
        public void Dispose() { }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
                //hook end request
                context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(OnEndRequest);
        }

        void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (clearCookies)
                {
                        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
                        var request = app.Request;

                        foreach (var cookieName in response.Cookies.AllKeys)
                        {
                                if (cookieName == "SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE" ||
                                        "SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE")
                                {
                                        response.Cookies.Remove(cookie);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

you have to create your own httpModule:

```
    <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="ClearCookieHttpModule, AssemblyName" name="ClearCookieHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

http://derekdysart.com/disabling-the-sitecore-analytics-cookie/

Answer (score 0):

This will still track the visit

I used a pipeline to patch the startAnalytics pipeline
and stopped the visit before it even started
with args.abortPipeline()