# How does Sitecore XDB handle a DNT=1 (do-not-track) request from a browser?

Tags: xdb, tracking

I have a client with a privacy policy that says we will respect the DNT header coming from a browser. Does Sitecore automatically not track DNT visits or do I specifically have to disable tracking for that visitor?

What is the best approach assuming the latter?

Comment: According to www.sitecore.net privacy policy ( http://www.sitecore.net/legal/privacy-policy ): `we do not look for or respond to "do not track" signals`. So I don't expect Sitecore has any built in mechanisms for that. I don't know what is the best option to make sure DNT forces not to track, but you could try to set visitor classification to `ROBOT` - guess Sitecore should not track the visitor in that case but I never tested it myself `Tracker.Current.Session.SetClassification(925, 925, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment suggests, the Sitecore does not react to the DNT signals, that is why you have to track it by yourself and stop the Analytics Tracker if there is a DNT header present.

You can check a DNT simply by checking the header value: `Request.Headers["DNT"]`

Please, refer to the below answer on how to stop tracking (personally, I suggest that you cancel the tracking in a pipeline processor): https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1456/982

Your code will look something like this:

```
var doNotTrack = Request.Headers["DNT"];
if( doNotTrack == "1" ) {
    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Enabled = false;
}
```